# Perl Replacing a complex regular expression with simpler method

Tags: regex, perl, url

**I have the following code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw(HELLO GOODBYE);  

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my $url = URI->new($_);
   my $query = $url->query;

foreach (@insert_words) {
  # Use package vars to communicate with /(?{})/ blocks.
  local our $insert_word = $_;

  local our @queries;
  if (defined $query) {
      $query =~ m{
          ^(.*[/=])([^/=&]*)((?:[/=&].*)?)\z
          (?{
              if (length $2) {
            push @queries, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
                  push @queries, "$1$insert_word$3";
                  push @queries, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
              }
          })
          (?!)
     }x;
  }

      if (@queries) {
          for (@queries) {
              $url->query($_);
              print $url, "\n";
          }
      }
      else {
          print $url, "\n";
      }
  }
}


__DATA__
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7
```

**The above piece of code works correctly and produces the following output:**

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO7    <-- precedes the query parameter
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO     <-- replaces the query parameter
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7HELLO    <-- succeeds the query parameter and so on for the rest of them....
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=7
```

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to get **exactly the same** output as shown above (so `foreach @insert_words` precede, replace and succeed each query parameter in the url), but I would like to replace the complicated regular expression method with a simpler, more easily understandable method, but I don't know the best way of going about it.

Your help with this will be much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: I believe this is the fifth question you have asked about this problem, and I don't see any evidence that you have actually written any code yourself during this process.  If you want someone else to do it, you need to hire someone.  If you want to learn Perl, you need to start with the basics and actually figure out how it works.

Comment: @dan1111 - I appreciate where your coming from, the reason for a number of questions is due to my requirement constantly changing slightly and new ways of doing it such as URI::QueryParam being shown to me that I did not know about, thanks

Comment: @perl-user, my point is that your process doesn't appear to involve any actual *learning*.  When you get a new requirement, you don't try anything but just come back to the site and ask for the solution again.  Lots of us are glad to help, but hopefully your goal is to become a better programmer yourself.  If you want to do that you need to engage with the problem more yourself.

Comment: @dan1111 - Yes you are correct and I understand your point - I have been attempting to do it myself as well, although granted I haven't been posting my own failed attempts for this problem. I have learnt a great deal from the solutions (as they are working practical examples rather than trivial programs like those found in books/online when trying to learn a new language) so I am in a better place to tackle similar problems myself now, and now I'm aware of the URI module and its derivatives, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described in the documentation for [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) how to handle queries. The [`URI::QueryParam`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aQueryParam) module supplies the `query_param` subroutine that allows interaction with the queries.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my @words = qw(HELLO GOODBYE);
my $URL = <DATA>;
my $uri = URI->new($URL);

for my $key ($uri->query_param) {                    # the keys of the query
    my $org = $uri->query_param($key);               # keep original value
    for my $word (@words) {
        for ("$org$word", $word, "$word$org") {   
            $uri->query_param($key, $_);             # set new value
            print $uri->as_string, $/;               # print new uri
        }
    }
    $uri->query_param($key, $org);                   # restore original value
}

__DATA__
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7
```

**Output:**

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE7
```